# Excel 2013 .xlsx files won't open

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, xls, xlsx

I am trying to open a file that I have created myself via a web API that I made for PHP. The file is created and downloads successfully but when I go to open it, I get this error:

> Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

I can use .xls files perfect, but not .xlsx.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the way you create the file.

Comment: @DavidPostill, what do you mean?

Comment: You created a file whose format does not match that defined for `.xlsx`

Comment: @DavidPostill, so the creator is wrong! That'll explain it... Time to take another look!

Comment: @Raystafarian, changing it to .zip didn't work, it downloaded but couldn't open

Comment: @Raystafarian, as I said in my question, .xls works perfectly, but the client specification is for .xlsx

Comment: There's no way to know what's wrong without seeing how your API is creating the file. This may be a stackoverflow question, if it were more clear.

Comment: @Raystafarian, if it helps, I have asked about this API, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041072/using-php-for-a-class-to-make-files-and-directories) is the likt to it

Comment: .xls files are completely different than .xlsx - the latter stores content like a container, the former does not.

Comment: Right. I'll do some research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use .xls files perfect, but not .xlsx.

XLS files and XLSX files are two different formats.
Excel cannot open an XLS files with a wrong extension `.xlsx` and it cannot open an XLSX file with the wrong extension `.xls`.

XLS is a proprietary binary format, while XLSX is an opened format based on XML files stored in a ZIP archive (just like LibreOffice).

If Excel does open the XLS file, then the file is XLS encoded.
So if you client specification is for XLSX then you have to change your code.

As your code is in PHP, of course I suggest [TBS + OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php). It works with the technical of templates.